# Removing Default Widgets in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, widget

Building my first WP theme and I quickly realized that I need to remove all the default widgets since I will be building my own.

So my question is what function do I need in my function.php file for this to happen =)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the code you're looking for:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_unregister_widgets' );

function my_unregister_widgets() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Archives' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Links' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Categories' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Search' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud' );
}
```

Comment: Here is a list of all widgets that you can remove: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget

Answer (score 3):

This is a much better solution.

```
remove_action( 'init', 'wp_widgets_init', 1 );
add_action( 'init', function() {  do_action( 'widgets_init' ); }, 1 );
```

This is future proof and better than letting WordPress register them then unregistering them.  This solution prevents the default widgets from even being registered.